# Wrapping text overlayed on HTML video

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to overlay text on top of a video element. My code so far is:

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
}

.container video {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  opacity: 25%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video type="video/mp4" src='data:video/mp4;base64,...'>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
  <div class="overlay">
    <p>OVERLAY TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly. However, the only issue is that when the overlay text gets too long, it doesn't wrap onto the next line, instead it stacks on top of itself. Is there a way to style this so that the overlay text wraps onto the next line and the whole overlay remains centered over the video? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Grid, you don't need the absolute positioning:

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "video";
  place-items: center;
}

.container video {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  grid-area: video;
}

.overlay {
  grid-area: video;
  color: white;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
  opacity: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video type="video/mp4" src='data:video/mp4;base64,...'>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
  <div class="overlay">
    <p>OVERLAY TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This results in the same effect, the text stacks on top of itself instead of wrapping around.

Comment: Is that what you see in the demo above? On my screen, the text scales with the browser width because of the font size setting.

Comment: Figured it out - it was the line-height:0 setting in the body style. Removing that lets the text wrap to the next line. Thank you!